# MyUICollectionViewCell is not visible

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "NewCell"

class SeondViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet var myNavBar: UINavigationBar!
    var frutta: [String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let margins = self.view.layoutMarginsGuide

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

        let newCollectionView: UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        newCollectionView.dataSource = self
        newCollectionView.delegate = self
        newCollectionView.register(SecondTabCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        newCollectionView.reloadData()
        newCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        newCollectionView.isHidden = false
        newCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(newCollectionView)

        frutta = ["Mele", "Olive", "Pere", "Noci", "Banane", "Kiwi", "Ananas"]
        myNavBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        myNavBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor).isActive = true
        myNavBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        newCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        newCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myNavBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        newCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    ◦           newCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height / 3)
    }
}

extension SecondViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return frutta.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SecondTabCollectionViewCell
        myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        myCell.secondCellLabel = UILabel()
        myCell.secondCellLabel.frame.size = CGSize(width: myCell.bounds.width / 2, height: myCell.secondCellLabel.bounds.height / 2)
        myCell.secondCellLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        myCell.secondCellLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        myCell.secondCellLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        myCell.secondCellLabel.text = frutta[indexPath.item]
        myCell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myCell.contentView.addSubview(myCell.secondCellLabel)

        return myCell
    }

}

extension SecondViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Hai premuto \(indexPath.row).")
    }

}

import UIKit

class SecondTabCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var secondCellLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) non e stato implementato.")
    }
}
```

Comment: newCollectionView.reloadData() after setting your array

Comment: I did it Bath it doesn’t work. I initialized my collectionView under a UICollectionViewFlowLayout object. Must I create a custom class of this type?

Comment: in bebug console I saw that the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little strange to be laying out a cell's internal views in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, this should be done in the cell class itself. The basic problem is that you your `UILabel` is appearing in the top left corner of the cell and has a height of zero, so you cannot see it. I moved the code you had in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` into the cell itself.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let myCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SecondTabCollectionViewCell
    myCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    myCell.secondCellLabel.text = frutta[indexPath.item]
    return myCell
}

import UIKit

class SecondTabCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var secondCellLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.textColor = .black
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configureViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

private func configureViews() {
    addSubview(secondCellLabel)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    configureLayout()
}

private func configureLayout() {
    let width = bounds.width / 2
    let height = frame.height / 2
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    let origin = CGPoint(x: width/2, y: height/2)
    secondCellLabel.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
}
```

}

Comment: I wrote exactly how you have shown me but I have this issue: “Cannot convert value of type .() -> _. to specified type .UILabel.”.

Comment: Did you remove or comment out the code for `secondCellLabel` in the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? I update my answer to include that method.

Comment: make sure that you have `()` at the end of the creation of the `secondCellLabel` variable. The variable is being created using a closure, and you need to execute the closure using the `()` at the end.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the extensions but then I tried to work with class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {...}“” too. After “override func viewDidLoad() {...}” my code is blocked. I don’t understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
myCell.secondCellLabel.frame.size = CGSize(width: myCell.bounds.width / 2, height: myCell.secondCellLabel.bounds.height / 2)
```

The above line is wrong in cellForItemAt, you put the height of label is myCell.secondCellLabel.bounds.height instead of myCell.bounds.height.

correct one is

```
myCell.secondCellLabel.frame.size = CGSize(width: myCell.bounds.width / 2, height: myCell.bounds.height / 2)
```